# XAML binding not working in C# UWP app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, uwp

i have a problem with binding an ObservableCollection in XAML

the class :

```
[DataContract]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string href { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ingredients { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

the Observable Collection :

```
private ObservableCollection<Result> resultTest;
```

the XAML code for binding :

```
<ListView Name="RecipeListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding resultTest}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Result">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Name="RecipeTitleTextBlock"
                                   Text="{Binding title}"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="24">

                        </TextBlock>

                        <Image Name="RecipeImage"
                               Source="{Binding thumbnail}"
                               Width="45"
                               Height="45">
                        </Image>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Everything seems to be correct as application launches, but there is no content visible that I was binding to.
Thanks you guys for any help.

Comment: btw, changing observable collection to public did not help

Comment: You can't bind to fields. Change it to `public ObservableCollection<Result> resultTest { get; set; }`. By the way, whenever you have an issue with a `Binding` check the Output window in Visual Studio for binding expression errors. They're helpful.

Comment: Did you set your DataContext?

Comment: Does this problem reproduce on the DEBUG and RELEASE configs or is there a difference there?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you're declaring "resultTest" as a "filed", not a property.
However, the binding system uses reflection to look for property, it does not look for "field".

Changing your resultTest declaration to property would solve the issue.

```
public ObservableCollection<Result> resultTest {get; private set;}
```

Also, make sure you have the DataContext properly set with xaml or code-behind like

```
this.DataContext = this
```

or

```
this.DataContext = new ViewModel()
```

Depending on what your DataContext really is.

My full MainWindow.cs looks like below, and the ListView binding works.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Result> resultTest { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        resultTest = new ObservableCollection<Result>();
        resultTest.Add(new Result() { title = "Hello" });
        resultTest.Add(new Result() { title = "World" });

        this.DataContext = this;

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. So i did what you said - changed collection to public property and wrote this.DataContext = this in the page constructor, but unfortunatelly it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: also changed the xaml (replaced Binding with x:Bind)

Comment: Did you add this.DataContext = this before or after the InitializeComponent()?

Comment: i added after InitializeComponent()

Comment: I've added my complete MainPage.cs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your datacontext set (i.e. in your code behind have `datacontext=this` or if you are using mvvm have your datacontext set in your window like this

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainViewModel/>
 </Window.DataContext>
```

And if you have your collection property setup like

```
public ObservableCollection<Result> resultTest {get;set;}
```

as Szabolcs Desi suggested then I would try removing the `x:Datatype="data:Result"` on your `DataTemplate`.  I tested the code you have minus that and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this dumb question , the problem was I was using a static method that returned an ObservableCollection to a variable. I thought I should remove it to a void function and fill the collection by foreach inside. Everything in xaml was right.